# How to skip random checking while booting Ubuntu on ASUS

Tags: boot, system-installation, asus

I would like to know how to skip this part that my laptop does before loading Ubuntu. Every time I boot up, it loads so much stuff as it is seen in the image below. How do I get my laptop to boot directly to Ubuntu? I'm a newbie here. Just installed Ubuntu on my hard drive after wiping it clean. It is not a dual boot.

[image]

Comment: Your laptop IS booting directly to Ubuntu. That's part of the boot. Viewing it is optional, but those steps will always occur whether you view them or not.

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot just shows the verbose output of the kernel start. If you don not want to see that (won't make anything faster) you should add the following in your `etc/default/grub` file:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

or extend your existing entry.

Also make sure that this line is not commented out (with a leading # sign)

If you want to know what slows your boot time, execute in a terminal:

`systemd-analyze blame`

As a result you will see which services take up the most time.

And you should consider the following: using gnome as a desktop (which is a resource hog) will take about 30% more boot time than xfce. (which Xubuntu has). It would be interesting to see  your output of the analyze command.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir. Noted. Although, I just checked the grub file you mentioned, and GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" was already there. Is there another  way for me get rid of it?

Comment: Make sure that line is not commented out with a leading hash. Paste the contents of the grub file into your question: `cat /etc/default grub`